# Entailment relationship?

Tags: semantics

Is this an example of entailment? Does A entail B?

A. None of Bob's friends have visited Africa. 
B. None of Bob's friends have visited Kenya.

But B seems to survive of A is negated: 
A'. Some of B's friends have visited Africa, but none have visited Kenya.

This does not seem like a contradiction.

Can someone shed some light on this question?

Comment: B entails A, not the other way round.

Comment: Negation changes the relationship.

Answer (score 2):

First we negate both sentences to see which one entails the other:

> Some of Bob's friends have visited Kenya **Therefore** Some of them
>   have visited Africa

This shows that B entails A. Let's see if it is true the other way around

> Some of Bob's friends have visited Africa **Therefore** They may or
>   may not have visited Kenya.